# 'ObjectId field is missing' error when using Esri Leaflet updateFeature

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I am trying to update a feature on the map upon click of a button. I am using updateFeature function of esri leaflet feature layer.

Here's the code that I have written:

```
layer_view_18.updateFeature({
    type: 'Feature',
    id: target.feature.properties.ID,
    geometry: geometry,
    properties: markerProperties
}, (err, response) => {
    console.log('response from updateFeature -- ', err);
    console.log('response from updateFeature -- ', response);
    // layer_view_18.redraw(target.feature.properties.ID)
});
```

The console show error saying 'ObjectId field is missing' and the response is undefined.

The map service layer has OBJECTID field defined in it along with other fields.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

I am following the [editing](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/editing.html) example from esri-leaflet documentation.

Is there something that needs to be changed in the code?

Comment: are you absolutely sure you are passing through the correct OBJECTID in the GeoJSON properties? you can find a working sample here: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/editable.html

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the comment. I was actually not passing the correct OBJECTID. The example shown above shows that I was passing the ID from the marker, but the updateFeature expects target.feature.id. This is shown in the example as well. My bad that I didn't read it before posting the question. The issue is sorted now. Thanks again.